# .length or .size() return extra values in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to get the length of children of a XML node. Other browsers seems to give exact result except the chrome. Suppose if the number of childs are six,chrome returns 13. Because of this the method `hasChildNodes()` or `hasChildren()` returns an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasChildNodes' of undefined` error. Could you please suggest me some alternatives so that I can run my code in Chrome.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "tree1.xml",
  dataType:"xml",
  success: function(xml){     

    var root=xml.documentElement;

    var childs1=root.childNodes;
    var len=$(childs1).size();

    alert(len);
```

Here is a part of the code where in I am alerting the number of children. The root element has 6 children.But chrome alerts 13

Comment: Are you using jquery for it?

Comment: can you make a minimal example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @user1996933 - code is unreadable in comments.  Please use the edit button and add it to your question and properly format it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.size()` anymore, it's deprecated since 1.8

Comment: "The childNodes collection contains all direct descendant nodes including text nodes and comment nodes." I don't know the original source but maybe browsers will interpret it differently?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `.children` instead of `.childNodes`.

The latter includes text nodes as well and so will typically return a higher number; worse, they don't support the same methods as elements do.

To determine the number of child elements you can use the `.length` property instead of wrapping it inside jQuery.

```
var childs1 = root.children;
var len = childs1.length;
```

Comment: This is not working.Says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefine`

Comment: @user1996933 Out of curiosity, what's the value of `xml` then?